# Make this view appear in every view, inside the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

[image]

This is a "curtain" hanging down from my navigationbar.

How can I have make this view as an overlay on all views in my app?
I must be able to add images to this overlay's subviews

Comment: I would probably extend a `UIView` and extend every other view from that view.

Answer (score 1):

Simply **add it to your application's key window**. That will overlay everything.

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:curtainView];
```

I use this method to present a full-screen progress indicator overlay (a singleton actually) to block the UI during some activities, regardless of context.

---

Please note that a UIWindow have no interface orientation, it is always aligned with the device, so rotating the UI is something to you have to handle if going this way (this actually indicates that this is not the best design).

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but you're right -- probably not an ideal design. I think it's better to work within the established system of a hierarchy of view controllers that manage content. In the past, yours was probably the simplest way to go, but now that we can write our own container view controllers I think that offers a cleaner design.

Comment: This design is never a good solution, regardless of time. :D It is just a really brief one-line solution for short term.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to get the effect you're looking for is to [create your own custom container view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html). That'll let you host other view controllers as children of your custom view controller, so you can have a single "curtain" that's on screen all the time even as the content underneath it changes.

Some of the advantages to a custom view controller compared to the other solutions are:

- **clean design:** none of the other views or view controllers in the app need to worry about the curtain
- **single instance:** the curtain will stay in place during view controller transitions
- **DRY:** seems to fit nicely with the "don't repeat yourself" concept

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve required with following steps --

1.) Create extension of `UINavigationController` for eg. `UINavigationControllerWithCurtain`.

2.) Override `initWithCoder` if you are constructing navigation with xib or else `initWithRootController` and add custom view of your curtain over `navigationcontroller's` view i.e. `self.view` itself in constructors.

3.) You need to override `pushViewController` method in order to set your custom curtain view at the top most layer so add following --

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewController:viewController animated:animated];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:customCurtainView];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Create a custom `UIView` (let's call it `curtainView`).
2. In whatever `init` method you plan to use for your views (`initWithCoder:` if they are loaded from XIBs or StoryBoard) put the code for creating the 'curtain' subview.
3. In this custom `curtainView` class, add a property for referencing the curtain subview.
4. Make all of your `UIView`s (NOT `UIViewController`s) subclasses of the `curtainView`.
5. Voila!

Comment: That means that you'll have a number of different instances of `CurtainView`, one for each view controller. If you push a controller onto the navigation stack, for example, you'll have one `CurtainView` slide into place over another. I'm not sure that's the effect the OP is looking for -- he'd probably prefer to have a single omnipresent instance of the view.