# Multiple UIWindows and touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

I have created a second window and add it on top of the default with :

```
[topWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
topWindow.hidden = NO;
```

it works but my top window block the access of the application's default window. I want to know if it's possible that if there is no element ( like a button for exemple ) in my top window at a given place of the screen, we can access to the elements of the default window at below.

I hope this is understandable.
Sorry for my english.
Thanks by advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you using two windows? iOS apps are expected to have only one window per screen. Can you use a view in place of the top window?

Comment: It's to have a layer at the top of my app which don't interfere with the main Window of my app

Comment: Strangely, your comment appears in French in my in box. Did you write it in French first and then edit it? Just wondering.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake with a copy and paste in google translation to check my English. But normally I have already correct my mistake.
Sorry !

Comment: I write this : "It's to have a layer at the top of my app which don't interfere with the main Window of my app"

Comment: No worries, the comment is in English -- I think the inbox just doesn't show the edit. Just seemed like SO had started translating to French, and perhaps [the singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity) was upon us.

Answer (score 1):

> I have created a second window and add it on top

So, I think the usual expectation is that there's just one window per screen in an iOS app. [The docs seem to imply this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/WindowScreenRolesinApp/WindowScreenRolesinApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012555-CH4-SW8):

> Every app has one window that displays the app’s user interface on an iOS-based device display. If an external display is connected to the device, an app can create a second window to present content on that display as well.

It's possible that iOS simply assumes that there's only one window per screen, and so the [hit-testing process](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW4) only considers one window, probably the key window. Since you're making your second window the key window, I'd suggest making the first window key after you create the second window and see if that changes things. It wouldn't be surprising if the first window then receives touches and the second doesn't. If you find that's the case, you might Subclass `UIWindow`, override `-hitTest:withEvent:` to pass the event to other windows if no hit view is found, and then use that subclass for both your windows.

Otherwise, if you can't get that to work, consider going back to a single window and using different views instead. Your question is somewhat similar to [Make this view appear in every view, inside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17165469/643383), and [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17432368/643383) there to create your own container view controller might help you.